# python importing a function in which I define a global variable

Tags: python, variables, global

I'm having difficulty accessing a variable.

I'm working toward the following, calling `python script` from `bash`, with arguments, which then imports a function defined in a second python script, executes it and thereby creates a variable which will be used later in the first python script.

At the moment,to test I'm copying and pasting directly into a Python terminal some commands like this:

```
from script2 import *
foofunction(arg)
print(newlist)
```

The foo function defined in `script2` is executing, I can see files have been written but when I try to print the list supposedly created while executing the imported function, I get a message telling me it's undefined.

Inside my `script2.py`, i made sure to enter a statement
    global newlist
before defining its length and populating it.

I'm scratching my head at this stage.

Comment: Please include the relevant code from script2.py :)

Comment: Why don't you `return newlist` in that function and assign it to a variable?

Comment: The `global` keyword does not work that way in python. Have a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/423379/using-global-variables-in-a-function)

Comment: I don't know why that didn't work when I tried it last night, but Graipher's solution is exactly correct. IF you want to throw that into an answer I'll gladly accept it.

Comment: `from some_module import *` is rarely a good practice as it mangles up your namespace.  This is a prime example - without the knowledge of `script2.py` we have no idea whether `foofunction` and `newlist` would be a `NameError` or an object that was defined in `script2.py`.  It's best to be *explicit*.

Answer (score -2):

You should refer to newlist and the module where it is defined like this:

```
from script2 import *
foofunction(arg)
print(script2.newlist)
```